# Why does LogonUser always return error code 1008?

Tags: c#, windows, security, winapi, windows-authentication

I'm using LogonUserA function to authenticate a user in an ASP.NET 4.0 web application that running on IIS7/Win2008. It works well if the user enters correct username and password, but in case username or password is wrong, LogonUserA always returns a same error code 1008 that translate to a vague message "An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist." Of course, if LogonUserA failed then there'll be no valid token, so what does this error mean? Is there any specific error code for typical login errors? And how can I get it?

Below is my code:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int LogonUserA(string lpszUserName,
    string lpszDomain,
    string lpszPassword,
    int dwLogonType,
    int dwLogonProvider,
    ref IntPtr phToken);

if (0 != LogonUserA(userName, domain, newPassword, Logon32LogonInteractive, Logon32ProviderDefault, ref token))
{
    // error is always 1008 if user name of password is incorrect.
    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

    var exception = new Win32Exception(error);

    // What I got in error log for above Win32Exception is:
    // System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got any solution yet.